# Passing multiple template variables to template tags in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

My problem occurs when I try to pass 3 variables to my template tag which I guess takes one or 2 inputs. So any ideas on how to pass 3 template variables to my template tag and here is my code:

views.py:

```
from shoghlanah.models import *

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_messages(sender_id,receiver_id,task_id):
    sender = UserProfile.objects.get(id = sender_id)
    receiver =UserProfile.objects.get(id = receiver_id)
    task = Task.objects.get(id=task_id)
    return messages
```

message.html :

the url.id and the task_id are template variables

```
{{ get_messages request.user.id usr.id task_id }}
```

it gives me an error : Could not parse the remainder: ' request.user.id usr.id task_id' from 'get_messages request.user.id usr.id task_id'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a django tag, you need to use `{% %}`, not the double curly brackets. The double braces signify outputting a value.

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-the-compilation-function) for more.

(Just as a note, I presume that is an extract, but you will also need to `{% load %}` your tag too.)